# JS recursive code not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to develop a chatroom to expand my knowledge of JS and jQuery, but I'm having a lot of trouble. I have a function that checks a text file and compares the amount of lines in it to the amount of lines in the chatroom; if there are more in the text file, the chatroom updates. I want this to be checked every 300 milliseconds.

When I began this project, I had a feeling `setInterval` was bad practice and I googled around a bit. I found [this tutorial](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/a-recursive-settimeout-pattern) and followed it; this did not work for me. How can I fix this code to use setTimeout properly?
(I've also noticed `setInterval` causing severe lag in Firefox).

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
setInterval(loadchat, 300);

function loadchat(){
var chatdisp = document.getElementById('chatdisplay');
$.get("chat.txt", function(data){
    var loadrowct = data.split("\n"); //split lines in the text file into array
    var currchat = $("#chatdisplay").html(); //lines currently loaded
    var currowct = currchat.split("<br>"); //split current lines into array

    if (loadrowct.length == currowct.length){
        //No need to update.
        return;
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            url : "chat.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                data = data.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
                console.log("Updated chat");
                if (chatdisp.scrollTop == (chatdisp.scrollHeight - chatdisp.offsetHeight + 6)){ //this adds 6 to make up for the CSS border
                    $("#chatdisplay").html(data);
                    document.getElementById('chatdisplay').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chatdisplay').scrollHeight;
                }else{
                    $("#chatdisplay").html(data);
                    $("#chatdisplay").css("border-bottom","3px solid #FF7700");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

I have looked into this online and seen this problem often, and I'm thinking there must be something I'm doing wrong, because nothing I try is working.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
function loadchat(){
console.log("Running the loadchat function");
var chatdisp = document.getElementById('chatdisplay');
$.get("chat.txt", function(data){
    var loadrowct = data.split("\n"); //split lines in the text file into array
    var currchat = $("#chatdisplay").html(); //lines currently loaded
    var currowct = currchat.split("<br>"); //split current lines into array

    if (loadrowct.length == currowct.length){
        //No need to update.
        return;
    }else{
        data = data.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
        console.log("Updated chat");
        if (chatdisp.scrollTop == (chatdisp.scrollHeight - chatdisp.offsetHeight + 6)){ //this adds 6 to make up for the CSS border
            $("#chatdisplay").html(data);
            document.getElementById('chatdisplay').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chatdisplay').scrollHeight;
        }else{
            $("#chatdisplay").html(data);
            $("#chatdisplay").css("border-bottom","3px solid #FF7700");
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function(){loadchat();},1000);
});
}

setTimeout(function(){loadchat()},1000);
```

Comment: I can't see why you need the second ajax call

Comment: oops... sorry, first time using jQuery's ajax functions, just overlooked that lol. thank you for telling me about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the two ajax calls into one. There's no reason for you to download the same file twice.

So something like:

```
if (loadrowct.length == currowct.length){
    //No need to update.
    return;
}else{
    data = data.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
    console.log("Updated chat");
    if (chatdisp.scrollTop == (chatdisp.scrollHeight - chatdisp.offsetHeight + 6)){ //this adds 6 to make up for the CSS border
        $("#chatdisplay").html(data);
        document.getElementById('chatdisplay').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chatdisplay').scrollHeight;
    }else{
        $("#chatdisplay").html(data);
        $("#chatdisplay").css("border-bottom","3px solid #FF7700");
    }
}
```

Second, your setInterval of 300ms is far too much. Try using a more conservative value like 2000ms - I bet some of your roundtrips were over 300ms so you experienced stacking of requests on top of each other (and thus slowing down firefox)

An even better method would be to call `setTimeout` only after your request completes - at the end of your function `$.get` callback function:

```
setTimeout(loadchat, 3000);
```

This will ensure a new request is initiated only when the old one completes.

Comment: thank you for showing me how to combine those! but i really would prefer the chatroom to be as responsive as possible--2000ms is pretty slow; is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Well you can set it back to your original value as long as you use `setTimeout`. Otherwise multiple requests could start overlapping, and I'm sure that's what you saw with Firefox slowing down.

Comment: I have added a setTimeout at the end of the `$.get` function and it doesn't seem to be recursing at all. Should I edit my original question with my attempt or link to the chatroom or something?

Comment: Did you initially call `loadchat()`?

Comment: BTW neither of these functions cause your function to "recurse". Recursion is when the function calls itself, and causes the function stack to grow. In this case, the function notifies javascript's main loop to call it again, and then it exits. The stack never grows, and when the new function is called, it cannot return its value to the previous function.

Comment: Yes, it is being called initially. I added a console message to show every time it runs; It is being called once initially and then once after that. It seems that the `setTimeout` is only working once. I'm going to edit the question with my attempt.